# Convert a 2D PHP array to a 2D Json object to plot on a graph

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, json

I'm working on this part of code since weeks now and I'm really unable to solve my issue. I'll try to explain my code deeply.

I'm fetching values from my MySQL database. Using the code below I'm able to create a 2D PHP array:

```
        for ($i=2, $k=2; $i<11, $k<11; $i++, $k++) {
            $roe_array[] = array( $date_y[$i] => $roe[$k]);
        }
```

The output of this code is the following

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [2006] => 13.83
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [2007] => 16.43
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [2008] => 14.89
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [2009] => 18.92
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [2010] => 22.84
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [2011] => 27.06
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [2012] => 28.54
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [2013] => 19.34
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [2014] => 18.01
        )

)
```

So, I convert the 2D PHP array in Json

```
$roe_enc = json_encode( $roe_array );
```

The output is:

```
[{"2006":"13.83"},{"2007":"16.43"},{"2008":"14.89"},{"2009":"18.92"},{"2010":"22.84"},{"2011":"27.06"},{"2012":"28.54"},{"2013":"19.34"},{"2014":"18.01"}]
```

Considering I have to plot it in a javascript script, I want an object like the following:

```
[[2006, 13.83],[2007, 16.43],[2008, 14.89],[2009, 18.92], [2010, 22.84],[2011, 27.06],[2012, 28.54],[2013, 19.34],[2014, 18.01]]
```

Can you help me to solve this issue?
Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now the year is a key and you want it to be a value in an array so you would have to generate an array that contains 0-based indexed arrays instead of key-value pairs. The reason is that any other index than a sequential 0-based ones get converted to a key-value pairs in json as javascript only knows 0-based arrays.

To do that you should change your loop to:

```
for ($i=2, $k=2; $i<11, $k<11; $i++, $k++) {
    // add an array with 2 values instead of a key-value pair
    $roe_array[] = array( $date_y[$i], $roe[$k] );
    //                               ^ add 2 elements instead of 1
}
```

Comment: Great jeroen, I'm a dumb! Thanks a lot. How can I have the $date_y as an integer? Because in this moment it's plotted like a float value

Comment: No problem Jeroen. It was an issue on the javascript script, not in the array code. Thanks a lot! +1 for you :)